# realizar una UPDATE en mysql desde Java

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas queria realizar una update en mi base de datos, mi problema es que tengo en mi base de datos una variable "id" autoincrementable y no me deja realizar la update este es mi codigo espero que podeis ayudarme, un saludo.

modificarcliente es mi JFrame donde ingreso los datos para mi UPDATE.

```
    public void modificarCliente(){

    Connection miConexion;

    Statement st;

    try {    
        miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fastfoodcompany","root", "quepasachavales3");

        st=miConexion.createStatement();

        Nombre=modificarcliente.getTxtNombre().getText();
        Apellido1=modificarcliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();
        Apellido2=modificarcliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();
        id=0;


        String query="UPDATE clientes SET id= '"+ id +"' AND Nombre= '"+ Nombre +"' AND Appelido1 = '"+ Apellido1 +"' AND Apellido2 = '"+ Apellido2 +"'";

        st.executeUpdate(query);


        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Datos actualizados");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(bdFFC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "No se han podido actualizar los datos"+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: El error que me da es el siguiente:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo el error esta en el query de sql, ya que la sintaxis correcta es:

`UPDATE <nombre de la tabla> SET <columnas a modificar> WHERE <condicion>`;
en tu caso no estas indicando la condicion con el where, por otro lado y como observacion no deberias cambiar el id, es solo observacion pero si los requerimientos lo indican puedes omitir mi comentario. saludos, espero responder tu duda.

Comment: Revisando el error que indicas se debe a que cuando no indicas un where todos los registros de la tabla son actualizados y como podras notar intentar asignar el id 0 a todos ellos, lo cual claramente dara un error de integridad.

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista, creo que tu error esta en la query que realizas

`String query="UPDATE clientes SET id= '"+ id +"' AND Nombre= '"+ Nombre +"' AND Appelido1 = '"+ Apellido1 +"' AND Apellido2 = '"+ Apellido2 +"'";` posiblemente tengas deshabilitado en tu base de datos, la opcion de poder realizar Updates sin un where. Ante esto hay 2 opciones:

1. Habilitar en la bbdd, la opcion de Update sin where (no recomendado)
2. Modificar tu query `String query="UPDATE clientes SET  Nombre= '"+ Nombre +"' AND Appelido1 = '"+ Apellido1 +"' AND Apellido2 = '"+ Apellido2 +"' where id = '"+ id +"'";`

Tambien te recomendaria que pusieras el nombre de las variables en minuscula.
`Nombre`deberia de ser `nombre`, al igual con las demas variables.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.